# Wordpress custom post status of "expired"

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I feel like this question has been asked before but the most recent query of it ([Custom post status not appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298346/custom-post-status-not-appearing)) was about two years ago so I'm wondering if anyone has any new information about it.

Looking to make a custom post status of 'expired' so that a post can be set to it using the 'post status' dropdown in the post editor and excluded from search. But if a old link drives a user to it, they can still see the content which is given a custom header of 'Expired'.

Any body have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use [custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields). Create a key/value pair of expired => true/false.

You can then retrieve the value using [get_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) and test it to add the header where required.

Comment: this is likely the simplest way still. it wasn't quite what i needed, but i'm not sure there's an easier way. thanks!

Comment: Your initial intention will be the best way to go - if it ever gets implemented (The ticket was created in 2010) - https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12706.