# Wordpress - change archive query to include post_status='archive'

Tags: php, wordpress, archive

The Wordpress 'Post' archive only display posts set to 'publish'.

I have a custom post_status called 'archive' to use. The logic of the database query should include:

```
post_status='publish' OR post_status='archive'
```

I cannot work out how or where this should go to influence the 'wp_get_archives()' function so I ask for your help in being able to influence the query to display posts set to 'archive' status. Thank you.

Comment: You must see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298346/custom-post-status-not-appearing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the [source code in the Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_archives/#source), the WHERE expression is filtered using 'getarchives_where'. So you can add:

```php
function custom_status_getarchives_where($where) {
    return str_replace( 'post_status = \'publish\'',
        '(post_status = \'publish\' OR post_status = \'archive\')',
        $where
    );
}

add_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'custom_status_getarchives_where' );
```