# Wordpress - custom post status is not showing

Tags: wordpress, post, status

I've created new post status. Here's code from my custom plugin:

```
add_action('init', 'new_post_status_add');

function new_post_status_add () {
    register_post_status('refused', array(
        'label'                     => _x('Refused', 'post'),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop('Refused <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Refused <span class="count">(%s)</span>'),
    ));
}
```

But it's not working - not visible in edit form and quick edit form:
[image]

What should I do to make status available?

Comment: I've encountered this problem several times already, so I decided to write an answer for myself :) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77752903/11977152

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for delayed reply. I hope my comment would help others.

**Custom Post Status** is an unsolved issue that has been there for such a long time, or at least since 8yrs ago on Wordpress website [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12706).

Wordpress noted on codex document for function `register_post_status()`:

> This function does **NOT** add the registered post status to the **admin panel**. This functionality is pending future development. Please refer
>   to [Trac Ticket #12706](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12706). Consider the action hook
>   [post_submitbox_misc_actions](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L183) for adding this parameter.

There is a work around that I could use for one of my projects. I mixed solutions that described on [this url](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/custom-post-status-quick-edit.html) and [this url](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/create-custom-post-status-mesasges-in-admin/).

The summary is that Wordpress doesn't show custom post status automatically. It needs to be manipulated by using your theme's `function.php`.

### First step

Create custom post status, same as you mentioned. just, don't forget that "This function should not be called before the 'init' action."

```
‌
function j_custom_post_status() {
$args = array(
    'label' => _x( 'Refused', 'post'),
    'label_count' => _n_noop( 'Refused <span class="count">(%s)</span>',  'Refused (%s)', 'post' ),
    'public' => false,
    'internal' => true,
    'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
    'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
);
register_post_status( 'j_refused', $args );

add_action( 'init', 'j_custom_post_status', 0 );
‌
```

I use [WP Generator](https://generatewp.com) to get the code snippet above.

### Second step

Tweak Admin Panel to show the custom status in Quick Edit Menu (QE) on posts list page `edit.php`. We need JQuery's help to do so and we need to add JQuery code to Admin Panel footer.

```
‌
function j_append_status_list(){

    //array of all custom status that you created
    $arr_customstatus = array(
        'refused',
        'other_custom_status',
        );

     echo '<script>';

     //flush
     $tmp = '';

     //generate string
     foreach ($arr_customstatus as $pkey ) {
         $tmp.= '<option value="'. $pkey .'">'. $pkey .'</option>';
     }

     echo "jQuery(document).ready( function() { jQuery( 'select[name=\"_status\"]' ).append( ". $tmp ." );
});";

     echo '</script>';

}
add_action('admin_footer-edit.php','j_append_status_list');
‌
```

Note: The function above doesn't automatically select the status in QE in case the post's status has been modified before. To add the `selected="true"` to the option, you need to use the `global $post` and check the current status, same as the the method used in the **Third step** below.

### Third step

Now, we need to add custom post status meta to post edit page too.

```
function j_custom_status_metabox(){

    global $post;

    $custom  = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $status  = $custom["_status"][0];

    // Array of custom status messages
    $arr_customstatus = array(
        'refused',
        'other_custom_status',
        );

        //Flush
        $tmp = '';

        foreach( $jstats as $pkey ) {

            if( $status == $pkey ){
                 $tmp.= '<option value="'.$pkey.'" selected="true">'. $pkey .'</option>';
             } else {
                 $tmp.= '<option value="'. $pkey .'">'. $pkey .'</option>';
             }
         }

     echo '<script>';

     echo "jQuery(document).ready( function() { jQuery( 'select[name=\"_status\"]' ).append( ". $tmp ." );
});";

     echo '</script>';

}
add_action('admin_footer-post.php','j_custom_status_metabox');
add_action('admin_footer-post-new.php','j_custom_status_metabox');
 ‌
```

### Step four

In case you like to show a message in posts lists based on custom post status, you can add this function too. However, this is optional.

```
function j_display_status_label( $statuses ) {

    global $post; 

    //Display label on all posts list but not on the custom status list
    if( get_query_var( 'post_status' ) != 'refused' ){ 
        if( $post->post_status == 'refused' ){ 
            return array('Refused'); 
        }
    }
    return $statuses; 
}

add_filter( 'display_post_states', 'j_display_status_label' );
‌‌    ‌
```

Note: The function above doesn't include all future custom status. You need to add `foreach` loop in case you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code,

```
// Register Custom Status
function custom_post_status() {

    $args = array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Refused', 'Status General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Refused (%s)',  ' (%s)', 'text_domain' ), 
        'public'                    => true,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
    );
    register_post_status( 'refused', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_status', 0 );
```

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `PHP_INT_MAX` to your `j_custom_post_status` action

```
add_action( 'init', 'j_custom_post_status', PHP_INT_MAX  );
```

‌

Comment: Didn't work for me. The top voted answer is probably an explanation as to why it doesn't work.